# jQuery if Form with Selects are Filled out, show div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am look for a way to make it so that when the user selects an item form all the select (for which the value of the option is not nil) the div with id "js-market" is shown.

This is my html code:

```
<form class="js-chose">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xm-12">
    <div class="form-group js-select">
        <label>Select a Market</label>
    <select class="form-control">
     <option value='' disabled selected>Chose a Market</option>
        <%Item.all.each do |item|%>
        <option value="<%=item.id%>"><%=item.name.capitalize%></option>
        <%end%>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-xm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter Market with:</label>
    <select class="form-control js-select">
        <option value='' disabled selected>Chose a Company</option>
        <%Company.where(user_id: current_user.id).each do |company|%>
        <option value="<%=company.id%>"><%=company.name%></option>
        <%end%>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In short I need to make jQuery show the div with id="js-market" when both selects have been filled by the user and get the values of the selected items and assign them to a variable.

Thank you. Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Example that works with multiple select elements**

Link to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bvv4xpp/3/)

```js
var counter = $('.select').length;
$('.select').change(function() {
    $.each($('.select'),function(i,e) {
        var t = $(this);
        if (t.val() == undefined || t.val() == '') {
            $('#js-market').fadeOut();
            return;
        }
        if (i+1 == counter) {
            $('#js-market').fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#js-market {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
    <option value="">No Value</option>
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="value1">Value 4</option>
</select>
<select class="select">
    <option value="">No Value</option>
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="value1">Value 4</option>
</select>

<select class="select">
    <option value="">No Value</option>
    <option value="value1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
    <option value="value1">Value 4</option>
</select>
<div id="js-market">Lorem ipsum</div>
```

Comment: How can I get the value of the selected options in JS to add them into another form in my html as a hidden input.

Comment: I've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5bvv4xpp/3/). You can change the input from text to hidden

Comment: How can I give the hidden input a name. The first company_id and the second market_id.

Answer (score 1):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1nzn14hg/)

You can do this by `onchange()` event in javascript. In the fiddle specified above, what I do is that, I've placed 2 select boxes and a div with id `demo` will be shown only if two of the select boxes are selected.

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelect1" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="mySelect2" onchange="myFunction()">
    <option value="0">--Select--</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("mySelect1").value > 0 && document.getElementById("mySelect2").value > 0) {
        document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "block";
    } else document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: How can I make this work: https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1nzn14hg/

With jQueries .hide and .show functions

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1nzn14hg/1/) that uses jQuery `hide()` and `show()`.